# In reactjs dropdown, how to pass specific value and not whole array?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dropdown

*I'm getting correct values in dropdown but after that when I'm calling onchange, whole array is getting passed as argument. so e has the whole array and not just the value selected
this is the code:*

```
const { accountIDs } = this.state;
let accountIDlist =
    accountIDs.length > 0 &&
    accountIDs.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <option key={i} value={item}>
                {item}
            </option>
        );
    }, this);

<Select
    style={{ width: "100%" }}
    defaultValue="123"
    autosize={true}
    onChange={e => {
        debugger;
        console.log(e);
        this.reset();
        this.setAccountID(e);
    }}
>
    <select value={accountIDlist}>{accountIDlist}</select>
</Select>
```

Comment: Why do you have both a `Select` component and a `select` as a child element inside it?

Comment: what would be the better way to do it?

Comment: Use the e.target.value

Comment: It really depends on what your `Select` component looks like.

Comment: The "select" inside should be an "option" tag, use a map function to render all options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to this would be:

```
    <Select
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        defaultValue="188619942792"
        autosize={true} 
        value = {accountIDlist}   
        onChange={e => {         
          this.reset()
          this.setAccountID(e)
        }}
         >
         
        {accountIDlist}

      </Select >
```

no need of child select component here.

Answer (score 0):

You main component should be managing the state, so load in the ids, and initially set `selected` to nothing. Then pass in the ids and selected state to your `Select` component. That will iterate over the ids to create the options, and if the id of an option matches that of the selection set the `selected` property.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Select extends Component {
  render() {
    const { ids, selected, handleChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        <option selected>Choose</option>
        {ids.map(id => {
          return (
            <option
              value={id}
              selected={selected === id}
            >{id}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { ids: props.ids, selected: '' };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selected: +e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { ids, selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <Select
        ids={ids}
        selected={selected}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }

};

const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example ids={ids} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select
  name="account_id"
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  {props.accountIDList.map((accountId) => <option value={accountId}>{accountId}</option>)}
</select>
```

You can set the default when you set up state like so... `const [accountId, setAccountId] = React.useState(account_id: 188619942792);`